# Use elements when DOM is fully loaded in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my child elements of body tag to be used when document is fully loaded. like I have

```
<body>
    Country: <br>
    <div>
        <datalist id="country"></datalist>          
        <input type="text" list="country" id="search" onmouseover = 'populate("country")'/>         
    </div>  
</body>
```

In the input element, i am using onmouseover event to call javascript function. But I want that thing to be enabled when all element are fully loaded.

Up till now, I have seen online that there is an **onload** event that can be used in body tag to call any particular function. But I don't want to call any function on onload event, just want to make sure that onmouseover event of input element should fired when body is fully loaded.

Comment: Try $(document).ready(function(){ }); function instead..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to listen on the `window` load event and then create your `mouseover` listener on the input whenever all media is fully loaded:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $("#search").on("mouseover", function() {
        populate("country");
    });
});
```

Instead of `window.load` you could even use `document.ready`. The first will even wait until all other things, like images, are loaded. The last will only wait until the DOM is finished ...

```
// $(function() {}) is a shorthand for $(document).ready(function() {});
$(function() {
    $("#search").on("mouseover", function() {
        populate("country");
    });
});
```

Comment: what if I want to make all elements, not to be used before window loaded. Elements can be any, having any event (rather than just mouseover).

Comment: That belongs to your actual project. One quick idea could be to hide the body by default and just show them whenever the page load has been finished. But as I said, that belong to your project. In general I don't see why you have to wait until `load`. That is a special case ...

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery for this

Your HTML code

```
<body>
    Country: <br>
    <div>
        <datalist id="country"></datalist>          
        <input type="text" list="country" id="search" />         
    </div>  
</body>
```

in you javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").hover(function(){
        populate('country');
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that `hover()` is not the same as a `mouseover` event - it's a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` combined

Answer (score 1):

In jquery use the

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').on('mouseenter', function(){
             console.log('mouse over');
          })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Country: <br>
    <div>
        <datalist id="country"></datalist>          
        <input type="text" list="country" id="search" />         
    </div>
```